# How to Add Record of Missing Row to Dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe:
`df`

```
    Name        Date ID  Amount
0   Faye  2018-12-31  A       2
1   Faye  2019-03-31  A       1
2   Faye  2019-06-30  A       5
3   Faye  2019-09-30  B       2
4   Faye  2019-09-30  C       2
5   Faye  2019-12-31  A       4
6   Faye  2020-03-01  A       1
7   Faye  2020-03-01  B       1
8   Mike  2018-12-31  A       4
9   Mike  2019-03-31  A       4
10  Mike  2019-06-30  B       3
```

And for each `Name`, `Date`, `ID`, group I calculate the % change of `Amount` from the previous `Date` in a new column. If there was no previous entry, then I add `New`:

```
df['% Change'] = (df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Name', 'ID']).Amount.pct_change())
df['% Change'] = df['% Change'].fillna('New')
```

But I also want to have an entry for the opposite case, where a `Name`, `Date`, `ID`, group *did* exist previously, but doesn't in the next date; so that the output looks like:

```
    Name        Date ID  Amount % Change
0   Faye  2018-12-31  A       2      New
1   Faye  2019-03-31  A       1     -0.5
2   Faye  2019-06-30  A       5        4
3   Faye  2019-09-30  A       0     Sold
4   Faye  2019-09-30  B       2      New
5   Faye  2019-09-30  C       2      New
6   Faye  2019-12-31  A       4      New
7   Faye  2020-03-01  A       1    -0.75
8   Faye  2020-03-01  B       1     -0.5
9   Mike  2018-12-31  A       4      New
10  Mike  2019-03-31  A       4        0
11  Mike  2019-06-30  A       0     Sold
12  Mike  2019-06-30  B       3      New
```

In case it helps, I am trying to emulate how [this site](https://dataroma.com/m/m_activity.php?m=BRK&typ=a&L=2) handles such cases.

Comment: Not sure I follow. I understand what you're doing right now. As to the 'opposite case': would you like 'sold' the override the pct_change as it's calculated right now, if there's no future date with the same name and ID?

Comment: Sorry, it's a little hard to explain but the site I linked to should help. Another way of looking at it is: imagine you're looking at inventory levels per product each quarter. In the 3rd quarter (2019-09-30), there's no longer an entry for Item A—presumably because you sold out. I still want to see a row for Item A in the 3rd quarter, but where it shows "Sold" (or -100%) in the % change column, and 0 in the Amount column (because there's none left).

Comment: okay. So to clarify - you'd like to add a new record for 'sold' items, in the first period in which they disappear from the inventory? (I think I understand the title of the post now).

Comment: Yes correct, but only in that first period and not subsequent periods. Unless of course it comes back into inventory again (and then sells out again)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution:

```
# run you original code to ide
df['% Change'] = (df.sort_values('Date').groupby(['Name', 'ID']).Amount.pct_change())
df['% Change'] = df['% Change'].fillna('New')

# Create a dataframe of all te dates. 
all_dates = pd.DataFrame({"Date": df["Date"].unique()}) 
all_dates["one"] = 1

# Create a dasta frame of all the possible recored (all combinations of id-name-date)
name_ids = df[["Name", "ID"]].drop_duplicates()
name_ids["one"] = 1

all_possible_records = pd.merge(all_dates, name_ids, on="one")
all_possible_records = pd.merge(all_possible_records, df, on = ["Date", "Name", "ID"], how ="left")
all_possible_records.drop("one", axis = "columns", inplace = True)
all_possible_records.sort_values(["Name", "ID", "Date"], inplace=True)

# For every record, shift 1 to see if it had any value in the previous querter. 
all_possible_records["prev_q"] = all_possible_records.groupby(["Name", "ID"]).shift(1)["Amount"]

# records in which change is NaN - but there was a value in the previous querter - are 'sold'
all_possible_records.loc[all_possible_records["% Change"].isna() & all_possible_records.prev_q.notna(), "% Change"]="Sold"

# Drop redundent records. 
res = all_possible_records.dropna(axis="rows", subset=["% Change"])
res
```

The result is:

[image]

Comment: Thanks but I don't think this is printing the percent change for `ID`s that do exist from quarter to quarter. They're all either `NaN` or `Sold`.

Comment: Not sure I follow. Do you have an example of where the result is wrong?

Comment: Well your screenshot looks correct, but when I run it on my machine I get `NaN` for the `% change` column on every row, except for the ones where the value is `Sold`

Comment: You should run your code first: df['% Change'] = (df.sort_values('Date').groupby(... I'll add it to my post.

Comment: Thanks this looks close, but there might be a slight miscalculation (I wonder if it should be `all_dates.Date.shift(-1)`? For example, `ID` `A` exists for `Faye` in dates: `2018-12-31`,`2019-03-31`, and `2019-06-30`, and then doesn't exist in the `2019-09-30` period. There should be a line item for that period where it shows as sold, but instead it never shows as `A` as having been sold by `Faye`.

Comment: Aha. So you're saying that the new line should not just appear for the last occurrence, but also whenever it's missing (but appears later). That's a slightly different problem, with a different solution. I'll update my post.

Comment: Well sort of. Check out the link I posted in the original question as that does a good job of visualizing what I'm trying to achieve. I think by changing it to `all_dates.Date.shift(1)` it might work, so I don't know if your answer needs a lot of reworking other than that?

Comment: Basically, the new line which shows `Sold` should only appear once, in the next period after it last appeared. So if it existed in `2019-03-31` but then not in `2019-06-30`, then I want to add an entry for it showing that it was sold for `2019-06-30` (and the `% change` -100%, and `Amount` = 0)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/214103/discussion-between-msd-and-roy2012).